# initiations pointer to arrays

Tags: c, pointers

```
    //1
    char** p;
    p[0]="Test";

    //2
    char** array;
    array = realloc(array, sizeof(char*)*((*size)+1));
    array[*size] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(input)+1));
```

Why does the first code fails in the second line, while the the second code works fine, doesn't  `array[*size]` is just like `p[0]`?

Comment: Where do you think `p` points to such that you can assign `p[0]`?

Comment: Both codws are wrong. Second code UB on the first realloc. Then probable many more

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer

Comment: @P__J__ If array was initialized to NULL it was ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examining the code:

```
char **p; // Declared, but uninitialized
p[0] = "test"; // Setting value to it?
```

`p` is uninitialized, and as such, trying to access and set memory with it is UB, or undefined behavior. Failing is much better than potential alternatives.

For the second piece of code, assuming size is some pointer not included in the snippet.

```
char** array
array = realloc(array, sizeof(char*)*((*size)+1)); // Allocating. 
array[*size] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(input)+1));
```

So, strictly speaking, calling realloc with an uninitialized pointer is UB, by chance array is equal to `Null`.

Note that:

> If ptr is NULL, the behavior is the same as calling malloc(new_size).

As such, realloc will allocate a chunk of memory and pass it to array.

You then dereference the pointer (which is no longer pointing to `Null` but a valid spot in memory), and malloc it, which does not crash.

From the best guess, while this is undefined behavior, p is possibly `Null` in both cases, and the first one crashes when trying to dereference it, and the second one successfully gets malloced.